# Converting polar coordinates (degree) to Cartesian line coordinates

Tags: metric-geometry

I am trying to calculate the *(x1,y1), (x2,y2)* coordinates of a line. From the image consider the rectangle of width *w*, height *h*, center *c* and angle *θ*.

[image: Image attached]

If the same is given in a graph with X and Y axis then we can draw a tangent with angle *θ* from the center to the edge of the circle. To calculate the point using formula, I know I can use

x = cos(θ) * r
y = sin(θ) * r

Is there a formula to find the x1,x2,y1,y2?

Comment: I don't know of a single formula but the only difference between the $ x_1, y_1$  and $x_2,y_2$ coordinates is that they have opposite signs if they are in mirror quadrants.

Comment: What circle do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the formulas $x=r\cos \theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, I suggest you just look at the triangle in your picture and use the definition of $\tan$ and $\cot$.

**Case 1:** $-\cot\frac{h}{w} \leq \theta  \leq \cot\frac{h}{w}$. In this case, the green line intersects the right vertical red side. Note that $x_1=\frac{w}{2}$ and $y_1 = x_1 \tan\theta = \frac{w}{2}\tan\theta$.

**Case 2:** $\cot\frac{h}{w} \leq \theta \leq \pi - \cot\frac{h}{w}$. In this case, the green line intersects the upper horizontal red side. Note that $y_1=\frac{h}{2}$ and $x_1 = y_1 \cot\theta = \frac{h}{2}\cot\theta$.

The remaining two following cases are similar

**Case 3:** $\pi-\cot\frac{h}{w} \leq \theta \leq \pi+\cot\frac{h}{w}$.

**Case 4:** $\pi+\cot\frac{h}{w} \leq \theta \leq -\cot\frac{h}{w}$.

Answer (score 0):

From $x=r\cos \theta,\; y=r\sin\theta$ you get $x=y\cot\theta.$

Notice that $$y_1=\frac{h}{2},$$ from the above you obtain $$x_1=\frac{h}{2}\cot\theta.$$

Can you find $x_2$ and $y_2?$